# Executing several commands at once

Tags: php, python, linux, perl

I am trying to write something in Perl (but I'm also happy with Python or PHP to do the same) which:

- Takes a list (of say, for example, files or URLs)
- Adds an additional system command (say `cp` as an example)
- Executes a maximum of ten these commands in the list of, say, a thousand in total
- Waits for one of the ten slots to become and starts a new procedure, thus moving through the 1000 elements.

I'm short-cutting right now and using back ticks to execute the commands in Perl, but if there is a better way to achieve this, I'd be really appreciative.

Comment: If the question is whether what you're currently doing is good practice then a minimal example of your code would help. If your question is how to do what you're already doing in another language then a minimal example of your code would help. Overall, the actual question and a minimal example of the code would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1087291/1331451

Comment: You must show what you have written, or we have no way of knowing what might be a "better way". You should probably take a look at [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show what you have written, or we have no way of knowing what might be a "better way"

You should probably take a look at [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager). Using that module your program could look something like this

There's a lot missing from this code, most importantly `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`, and the declaration and population of `@list`. I trust that you can fill in the blanks

Note that the limit on ten parallel process is imposed by the module, and that `"..."` must be filled in by yourself as the destination path. It's always best to do what you need within Perl instead of shelling out just to call `cp`, so I've involved [`File::Copy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy) instead

```
use Parallel::ForkManager ();
use File::Copy 'copy';

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);

for my $file ( @list ) {

    next if my $pid = $pm->start;

    # Child code

    copy $file, "...";
    $pm->finish;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Perl Dog that was exactly what I was seeking. To respond to previous posts - apologies, I had about five variants in two languages and felt it best to put the concept down of what I was trying to do vice scrappy code :) Apologies and will follow the rules next time! Thanks again all for taking the time to respond.